# Python email validation mx check fails

Tags: python, validation, email

I was using this [py3-validate-email](https://pypi.org/project/py3-validate-email/) package in the project, it was working fine before, but now it started failing, I can see that mx check gets fail, here are my tryouts

```
In [2]: from validate_email import validate_email                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [3]: is_valid = validate_email(email_address='<some-mail-id>')                                                                                                                                                           
Validation for '<some-mail-id>' failed: Email address undeliverable:
alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
aspmx2.googlemail.com.: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
aspmx.l.google.com.: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
aspmx3.googlemail.com.: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

In [4]:
```

Some external URLs are unreachable, I request you to please let me what will be an issue, whether it is a package issue or something else I am missing, please suggest me some solution. it will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a real email address ??

Comment: Look in the package's [FAQ](https://github.com/karolyi/py3-validate-email#faq), they give some information about being rejected.

Comment: @Lucino772 Yes tried with valid email id only....

Comment: Did you check the link I sent you

Comment: Yes I went, now checking for port 25 in my machine

Comment: @Lucino772 Thank you so much for guiding me, the problem is my internet connection in which port 25 is not working, and I tried changing my internet connection and now its working.....thanks a lot